# Change background color of a Qlayout containing QButtons

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have this Qt code:

```
QHBoxLayout *taggerBox = new QHBoxLayout;
falseBtn = new QToolButton;
falseBtn->setText(tr("False"));
voidBtn = new QToolButton;
voidBtn->setText(tr("Void"));
taggerBox->addWidget(falseBtn);
taggerBox->addWidget(voidBtn);
```

I would like to change the background of the QHBoxLayout (NOT the background of each button). I didn't find any way to change the background color of a QLayout.

How can I do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

QLayout is not a visual element, it's a container that adjust location of contained widgets. You can change background of QFrame or other widgets you included QLayout into.

Answer (score 3):

Since `QHBoxLayout` is not a `QWidget` it hasn't its own appearance. So you can't change its color.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to add an intervening widget that you set the layout on, and change that widget's background. E.g.

```
auto *taggerBox = new QWidget;
auto *layout = new QHBoxLayout(taggerbox);
falseBtn = new QToolButton(tr("False"));
voidBtn = new QToolButton(tr("Void"));
layout->addWidget(falseBtn);
layout->addWidget(voidBtn);
auto palette = taggerBox->palette();
palette.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::blue);
taggerBox->setPalette(palette);
```

If you're doing this in the constructor of some class, then likely the objects have the same lifetime as the class as there's no point to dynamically allocate them. In such circumstances, the widgets and layouts should be class members instead:

```
class MyClass : ... {
  QWidget taggerBox;
  QHBoxLayout taggerLayout{&taggerBox};
  QToolButton falseBtn{tr("False")};
  QToolButton voidBtn{tr("Void")};
public:
  MyClass(...);
};

MyClass::MyClass(...) : ... {
    taggerLayout.addWidget(&falseBtn);
    taggerLayout.addWidget(&voidBtn);
    auto palette = taggerBox.palette();
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::blue);
    taggerBox.setPalette(palette);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Static members might no longer work properly with Qt 4.8 and later, because that implies  possibility of either destructor bomb or attempts  of call to members of destroyed objects. Thing is that Qt automatically deletes child widgets and owned layouts. Issue is if if object is destroyed by call to destructor outside of framework, the message pump might still address it  after destruction. It's more likely with complex GUI where some elements are updated by timer, by messages from other threads, etc.

Comment: That's not true. I have no idea what you mean by "destructor bomb". Qt only deletes children that exist. If you get rid of a child, it doesn't exist by definition, and Qt would be **very** broken if it tried to mess with children that don't exist anymore. Since C++ had specified the order of class member construction and destruction for decades, it's not hard at all to order the members in the correct way. I have hundreds of thousands of lines of projects in total, all written this way.

Comment: There's no such thing as "a call to destructor outside of framework" -- I mean go ahead: try and provide an example (code, not words). No clue what that would even mean. Qt objects, like QObject, are just C++ classes, and proper RAII classes at that. They can be destroyed at any time, by anyone, and when they are destroyed, they wipe any events pending for themselves, as well as any references to themselves. There's a reason why Qt has quite on the order of 1k lines of code dealing with various corner cases on that.

Comment: All member objects that have the same lifetime with the owning object should be held by value, by C++ semantics that Qt doesn't (and can't!) alter. If an object's lifetime ends before that of the owning object - then indeed it must not be held by naked value. `std::optional` works for that, or explicit dynamic allocation via a smart pointer - or via parent object.

Comment: You actually was called out before about this point of view. And one of examples given was link to this article: http://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects When message loop is involved, private implementation of widgets own its children even if you don't put them into class. Forcing them to be destroyed by class destructor enforces particular order. Removing widget from tree automatically forces framework to try/delete its childrens. What if order would be different? Also, how platform would deal with double deletion? This doesn't work on all platforms, what I saw myself.

Comment: C++ has a fixed destruction order, and you order children after their parents. Simple. Removal of any child will neither force Qt to remove the siblings nor the parents, and of course the destructor invocation order + all children of a parent having to be declared after the parent in the member list of the class, to avoid UB per basic C++ rules - simply leverages it. The children will be gone before the base class's `~QWidget` gets going. No double deletion. I can't divine what the problem was in your case, but I don't know of any code in Qt codebase that would precipitate this. It'd be bad.

Comment: But if you have a reproducer and a description of the platform and Qt version that didn't work, I'll gladly look at it. If the code is solid, it'd be a clean-cut Qt bug. Perhaps there's some corner case I never ran into - but it's absolutely supposed to work, lots of code in Qt itself would break if it didn't.

Comment: The only valid way of being "called out" on something that supposedly inherently has UB (e.g. crashes) is to be given a hopefully simple example that reproduces the issue under e.g. valgrind or another runtime memory checker. I mean - if this approach is so fundamentally broken, providing a simple example should be trivial. woboq has an awesome code browser for Qt as well. I take English prose into consideration, but ultimately the code is the standard of truth here. After being pestered enough about something and being shown no code, I lose interest. And so should anyone, really.

Comment: After all, at the end of the day, this site is for discussion of code, not trading stories.

Comment: I'm having soo much trouble with this it's unreal. I think the background image in the application is overwriting the background colour in the widget.